# How to show latest product in opencart manually

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I want to show latest product in home.tpl opencart 1.5.6.4 manually without using latest module. How to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Use the `Featured` module!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Faiz, You can manually select product from featured module from admin side so it will show in the home page.